# Existence/value of the integral of a rational function using gamma function and complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, gamma-function

The value of the integral $\displaystyle\int^\infty_0\frac{x^n-1}{x+1}\ \mathrm dx, $ for $0<n<1$, is $\frac{π}{\sin nπ}$.

Here, to solve this, I took $x=\tan^2t          \ \  \ \ (1)$

$\implies \mathrm dx=2\tan t\cdot\sec^2t\ \mathrm dt$

Lower & Upper limit : putting $x=0$  & $\infty$ in $(1)$ gives      $ \ 
\ t =0$ & $π/2$ respectively.

Now substituiting all those values we get
$\displaystyle\int^\frac{π}{2}_0\frac{(\tan^{2n-2}t)2 \tan t\sec^2t}{1+\tan^2t}\ \mathrm dt$

Or $\displaystyle\int ^\frac{π}{2}_0\sin^{2n-1}t\cos^{1-2n}t\ \mathrm dt$

After this, I don't get how to proceed towards the answer.

Comment: This integral diverges unless $n<0$?

Comment: I knew a theorem(IV)pg-578 from advanced calc. By Taylor & mann, that provides for a series $u_n=f(n)$ where $n≥N$ "$u_n$converges or diverges according as the integral $\int^\infty_N f(x) dx$ is convergent or divergent". Unfortunately i dont know any theorem conditioning it conversly.

Answer (score 2):

Due to the substitution $\frac{1}{1+x}\to u$, Euler's Beta function and the reflection formula for the $\Gamma$ function we have

$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\color{red}{x^n}}{x+1}\,dx = \color{red}{-}\frac{\pi}{\sin(n\pi)}\quad\text{for any }\color{red}{n\in(-1,0)}$$

while the integral $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^n}{x+1}\,dx$ is *divergent* for any $n\geq 0$.

Comment: I may be able to understand if you approach the answer step by step, where your approach is different from mine.

Comment: @kunalCh. you are starting with a claim which is blatantly false, but the substitutions $\frac{1}{1+x}\to u$ or $x\to\tan^2\theta$, *if applied to a convergent integral*, both lead to the same outcome (a value of a Beta function which boils down to a value of the $\text{csc}$ function)

Comment: Glad to learn something new. But still the point is missing i.e. i am unable to grasp it. Either kindly simplify your answer or proceed from where i left.